# How to create var name with multiple var using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create create var name `a_test_3_check` from multiple var and text using javascript For this code , i want to alert `test`

I tried to do with this code but not work. how can i do ?

```
<script>
var a_test_3_check = "test";

var x = "test";
var y = "check";

var z = 'a_'+x+ '_3_' +y;
alert(z);
</script>
```

And when i test code i alway alert `a_test_3_check`, how can i do ?

Thank you for every question.

Comment: Just getting my comment in before someone posts an answer using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval): if you run into a situation where you have to dynamically construct and evaluate variable names, there is most likely something wrong with your design. Explain what you're trying to achieve, and we can help you think of alternatives.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen To expand on this there is **never** a reason why you would need to do this. The name of a variable should have not have an impact on the functionality of your code.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek We are in complete agreement. Yet, there are already two `eval()` answers and they are even getting upvoted.

Comment: Don't do that. You should not generate variable names dynamically. At the most, you should create a JavaScript object and then get the value, based on its key, which is perfectly fine. Read [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Did you try my solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you try with `eval()` then you will get what you want.

```
var a_test_3_check = "test";

var x = "test";
var y = "check";

var z = 'a_'+x+ '_3_' +y;
alert(eval(z));
```

**BUT, YOU SHOULD NOT USE**  `eval()` coz its not the proper way to get variable of variable, try using object structure though.

```js
var obj = {
  x: "test",
  y: "check",
  a_test_3_check: "test"
};

var z = 'a_' + obj.x + '_3_' + obj.y;
console.log(obj[z]);
```

Comment: down voter, see my edit.. I wast writing the code, in the meantime you just down voted twice.Didn't wait for my full answer :(

Comment: 1) Nobody can downvote twice 2) If you want people to wait for your complete answer before they vote, don't post before you have a complete answer.

Comment: Yes, I totally agreed with you sir. Sorry it was my bad :(  to click on post button before completing my answer. One more thing twice means two person, my English is not that good :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`, it is a very bad practice. Though, to use a variable value as a variable name, wrap the variable between square brackets (`[]`) after the object containing the variable instead of writing a dot followed by the variable name. For example:

```
// Instead of writing this
obj.variableName

// Write the following
obj[varContainingName]
```

If you want to do the same but for the global scope it is different for every node execution environment. If you're writing javascript for the front end use `window` as your object (`obj`). For server side JavaScript, I'm not sure if there's a way to declare *global* variable but anyway it would not be a good practice. Instead, you should declare your object variables in your module and if you need them in another module export them. For example:

*module1.js*

```
let obj={};
module.exports = obj;

// Or if you need to do some operations before exporting your variable
// Just wrap it in a function
module.exports = (function() {
    // Do your operations here
    return obj;
})();
```

*module2.js*

```
// Import your obj
const objFromModule1 = require('./module1.js');
// And do whatever you want to do with the variable
```

Though, the changes applied to the variables imported from other modules will only be visible to the current module until you export the variables with the changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval()`, If the argument to this function represents an expression, `eval()` evaluates the expression. If the argument represents one or more JavaScript statements, `eval()` evaluates the statements

`var z = eval('a_'+x+ '_3_' +y);`